# INNER JOIN SELECT in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-update, inner-join

I have an SQL statement that works in SQL Server but fails in MySQL... shouldn't this work in MySQL?

```
UPDATE T2
    SET TotalAmount = T1.SumAmount
    FROM ccs_multiples as T2
    INNER JOIN (SELECT SUM(Amount) as SumAmount, SerialNumber
                FROM ccs_multiples_items
                GROUP BY SerialNumber) as T1
    ON T2.SerialNumber = T1.SerialNumber
```

Error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near `FROM ccs_multiples as T2 INNER JOIN (SELECT SUM(Amount) as  SumAmount, Seria` at line 3

Comment: Please describe "*fails*".  Any error messages? Unexpected behavior?

Comment: **MySQL said:**
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM ccs_multiples as T2
    INNER JOIN (SELECT SUM(Amount) as SumAmount, Seria' at line 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When updating with a `JOIN`, instead of doing a `JOIN`, you can specify multiple tables in the update, ie.

`UPDATE table1 t1, table2 t2`

and then specify what would typically be your `JOIN` condition, instead as part of your `WHERE` condition, like

`WHERE t1.someCol=t2.someOtherCol`

So instead of a join, you could write your query like this

```
UPDATE 
  ccs_multiples T2,
  (SELECT 
    SUM(Amount) AS SumAmount,
    SerialNumber 
  FROM
    ccs_multiples_items 
  GROUP BY SerialNumber) T1 
SET
  T2.TotalAmount = T1.SumAmount 
WHERE T2.SerialNumber = T1.SerialNumber
```

Comment: Are you implying that MySQL doesn't support `INNER JOIN` syntax?

Comment: @PM77-1 I'm not implying anything. It's just how i would do it. If you have a solution that preserves the inner join, please advise

Comment: @Mark please elaborate

Comment: This seems to work...
`UPDATE ccs_multiples as T2
    INNER JOIN (SELECT SUM(Amount) as SumAmount, SerialNumber
    FROM ccs_multiples_items
    GROUP BY SerialNumber) as T1
    ON T2.SerialNumber = T1.SerialNumber`

Comment: if total amount is part of `css_multiples` then `T2.TotalAmount` or just `TotalAmount` should be the same thing

Comment: MySQL doesn't like the syntax where you put `UPDATE T2` first.
MSSQL doesn't mind.

Comment: @Mark what does it say about it? I don't get why it would care. Curious. What error do you get?

Comment: I may have spoken too soon... I'm getting 0 rows affected from this fix

Comment: Ahhh... because the TotalAmount was already equal to the SumAmount

Comment: @Mark, it couldn't have been the "MySql Said error above" because that references the inner join, which this solution does not have

Comment: @chiliNUT: this solution does have an inner join. It's just being expressed with the old-school comma syntax for a join operation, rather than the `JOIN` keyword. Using the `JOIN` keyword, we also have the option of relocating the join predicate(s) from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause. (It's not accurate to say that "this solution does not have" an inner join. This solution uses a comma in place of the `JOIN` keyword, but it's still an inner join operation.)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for a multi-table update in MySQL is different than SQL Server.

You can use syntax like this:

```
  UPDATE ccs_multiples T2
    JOIN ( SELECT SUM(i.Amount) AS SumAmount
                , i.SerialNumber
             FROM ccs_multiples_items i
            GROUP BY i.SerialNumber
         ) T1
      ON T2.SerialNumber = T1.SerialNumber
     SET T2.TotalAmount = T1.SumAmount
```

NOTES:

In MySQL, the `INNER` keyword is optional; omitting it has no effect on the statement.

But, what would you want to do with rows in `ccs_multiples` that don't have any corresponding rows in `ccs_multiples_items`. To set the `TotalAmount` column to zero for those rows, you could use an outer join:

```
  UPDATE ccs_multiples T2
    LEFT
    JOIN ( SELECT SUM(i.Amount) AS SumAmount
                , i.SerialNumber
             FROM ccs_multiples_items i
            GROUP BY i.SerialNumber
         ) T1
      ON T2.SerialNumber = T1.SerialNumber
     SET T2.TotalAmount = IFNULL(T1.SumAmount,0)
```

---

One thing to note about the MySQL syntax, we can (usually) convert a `SELECT` statement into an `UPDATE` statement. I usually start with a `SELECT` to test the predicates and the expressions. For example:

```
SELECT T2.SerialNumber
     , T2.TotalAmount          AS existing_TotalAmount
     , T1.SumAmount
     , IFNULL(T1.SumAmount,0)  AS new_TotalAmount
  FROM ccs_multiples T2
    LEFT
    JOIN ( SELECT SUM(i.Amount) AS SumAmount
                , i.SerialNumber
             FROM ccs_multiples_items i
            GROUP BY i.SerialNumber
         ) T1
      ON T2.SerialNumber = T1.SerialNumber
```

We can test that SELECT, and verify that the expressions are working correctly. To convert that into an UPDATE statement, we just remove the **`SELECT ... FROM`** from the beginning of the statement, and replace it with **`UPDATE`** and add a **`SET`** clause before the `WHERE` clause.